# Parameter Object Destructuring with Required Values and Empty Object

Tags: javascript, object, parameters, required, destructuring

Using ES6 parameter object destructuring we can require the presence of certain properties, as well as, provide [default values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Setting_a_function_parameter%27s_default_value). [Dr. Axel Rauschmayer](http://dr-axel.de/) said in the [Six nifty ES6 tricks article](http://www.2ality.com/2016/05/six-nifty-es6-tricks.html) that parameter default values are only evaluated when they are actually used.

The next example will provide more context about what I do not understand:

```
function ajax({
  type = requireParameter("type"),
  url = requireParameter("url"),
  data = requireParameter("data"),
  success = requireParameter("success"),
  error = requireParameter("error"),
  isAsync = requireParameter("isAsync")
  } = {}) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify({
      type,
      url,
      data,
      success,
      error,
      isAsync
    }, null, 2));
};

function requireParameter(name) {
  throw new Error (`Missing parameter "${name}"`);
}

try {
  ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "http://my.api.io",
    data: {},
    success: () => {},
    error: () => {},
    isAsync: true
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.warn(e.message);
}
```

Having the `{...} = {}` or just `{...}` on the `ajax` first argument function will have the same behavior. So when I test one of the two options I can not conclude what does the `{...} = {}` logic do.

The question that I made here is:

Why do we need the object to be equal to an empty object on the first argument of the `ajax` function?

Comment: The `{...} = {}` in your function parameters simply sets the default value if the argument passed is undefined.

Comment: Yes, but why do I need that? Since having the `{...} = {}` or just `{...}` will have the same output.

Comment: So imagine you do this: `ajax(undefined)`. You cant destructure undefined, so the whole type checking is futile. So you set the default value of the first argument be an empty object, which can be destructured :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular example, you don't need to default the destructed object to an empty object since your intended behaviour is to throw an exception when a parameter is missing. You could default the object with it's properties like so for when no argument is provided:

```js
function ajax({
  type = requireParameter("type"),
  url = requireParameter("url"),
  data = requireParameter("data"),
  success = requireParameter("success"),
  error = requireParameter("error"),
  isAsync = requireParameter("isAsync")
} = {
    type: "get",
    url: "http://my.api.io",
    data: {},
    success: () => {},
    error: () => {},
    isAsync: true
  }) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify({
      type,
      url,
      data,
      success,
      error,
      isAsync
    }, null, 2));
};

function requireParameter(name) {
  throw new Error (`Missing parameter "${name}"`);
}

try {
  ajax(/* Don't provide anything and use the default */);
} catch (e) {
  console.warn(e.message);
}
```

Comment: But when do I need or do not need in that case?

Comment: It depends on how you want the function to be used. Do you want it to be a required argument? If so, don't use a default for the argument and use the `requireParameter` structure that you already have. Otherwise, use a reasonable default.

Comment: This is just an example for understanding the parameter object destructuring with required values mechanic.